# MATLAB: How to plot a cubic expression for certain range of input pressure

Tags: matlab

I have a cubic expression here

[image: cubic expression here]

I am trying to determine and plot *δ* in the expression for *P* values of 0.0 to 5000. I'm really struggling to get the expression for *δ* in terms of the pressure *P*.

```
clear all;
close all;

t = 0.335*1e-9;
r = 62*1e-6;
delta = 1.2*1e+9;
E = 1e+12;
v = 0.17;
P = 0:100:5000

P = (4*delta*t)*w/r^2 + (2*E*t)*w^3/((1-v)*r^4);
```

I would appreciate if anyone could provide pointers.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [functional inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of your expression, i.e., *δ* as a function of *P*. Since it's a [cubic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), you can expect up to three solutions (roots) for a give value of *P*. However, I'm guessing that you're only interested in real-valued solutions and nonnegative values of *P*. In that case there's just one real root for each value of *P*.

Given the values of your parameters, it makes most sense to solve this numerically using [`fzero`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html). Using the parameter names in your code (different from equations):

```
t = 0.335*1e-9;
r = 62*1e-6;
delta = 1.2*1e9;
E = 1e12;
v = 0.17;
f = @(w,p)2*E*t*w.^3/((1-v)*r^4)+4*delta*t*w/r^2-p;

P = 0:100:5000;
w0 = [0 1]; % Bounded initial guess, valid up to very large values of P
w_sol = zeros(length(P),1);
for i = 1:length(P)
    w_sol(i) = fzero(@(w)f(w,P(i)),w0); % Find solution for each P
end

figure;
plot(P,w_sol);
```

You could also solve this using symbolic math:

```
syms w p
t = 0.335*sym(1e-9);
r = 62*sym(1e-6);
delta = 1.2*sym(1e9);
E = sym(1e12);
v = sym(0.17);
w_sol = solve(p==2*E*t*w^3/((1-v)*r^4)+4*delta*t*w/r^2,w);

P = 0:100:5000;
w_sol = double(subs(w_sol(1),p,P)); % Plug in P values and convert to floating point

figure;
plot(P,w_sol);
```

Because of your numeric parameter values, [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) returns an answer in terms of  three [RootOf objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#buhfj3h-1), the first of which is the real one you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @horchler Exactly what I wanted. You're the man

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two simple methods.

1. You evaluate `P` as a function of `delta` then you `plot(P,delta)`. This is quick and dirty but if all you need is a plot it will do. The inconvenience is that you may to do some guess-and-trial to find the correct interval of `P` values, but you can also take a large enough value of `delta_max` and then restrict the x-axis limit of the plot.
2. Your function is a simple cubic, which you can solve analytically ([see here if you are lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)) to invert `P(delta)` into `delta(P)`.

Comment: Thank you @Emerald truly appreciate